# Page Redirect and set request custom request header

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to redirect to another web app and set a custom request header. This is manly because the web app that I am going to is expecting a custom header for the user name call "REMOTE_USER" where I will set the user name to.

I was exploring the use of a java servlet or maybe writing some java script to do this.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("POST", "/log");
  client.setRequestHeader("REMOTE_USER", "User1");

window.location.href = "http://myserver.com:8080/webapp/";
```

I am seeing that the page is getting redirected but don't see any custom request headers

Answer (score 0):

```
function customHeader(remoteinput, userinput) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("POST", "/log");
    client.setRequestHeader(remoteinput, userinput);

    window.location.href = "http://myserver.com:8080/webapp/";
}
```

Now execute your function:

```
customHeader("something", "user42");
```

If I am misinterpreting your question, please reply!

Comment: I am getting the same result. I think I need to add more information to my first question.

Comment: If you do, I think I might be able to answer more specifically.